# Spherical harmonics give all the irreducible representations of $SO(3)$?

Tags: representation-theory, special-functions, harmonic-analysis, spherical-harmonics

It is mentioned in [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics#Connection_with_representation_theory) that the spaces $\mathcal{H}_{k}$ of spherical harmonics of degree $k$ give ALL the irreducible representations of $SO(3)$. Could anyone tell me where can I find the proof? Thanks!

**EDIT:** I am seeking for an elementary proof that dose not require too many big machineries in representation theory.

Comment: [Bröcker-tom Dieck](http://books.google.com/books?id=AfBzWL5bIIQC) is a very accessible source for such things.

Comment: Dear Xianghong, What is your background?  If you know a little bit about how to pass between Lie group representations and Lie algebra representations, then this is easily verified, using highest weight theory for the Lie algebra ${\mathfrak sl}_2$.  Regards,

Comment: @t.b.: Thanks! It's helpful.

Comment: @Matt E: But representations of the Lie algebra are not necessarily the representations of the group? And how are the representations of $SO(3)$ related to the representations of $sl_2$?

Comment: @XianghongChen: Dear Xianghong, That's right; the representations of the Lie algebra correspond to representations of the simply connected cover, e.g. in the case of $SO(3)$, reps. of its Lie algebra corresond to reps. of its simply connected cover $SU(2)$.  But it's not hard to figure out which of these reps. actually come from reps. of $SO(3)$; one just uses the fact that $SO(3) = SU(2)/\langle \pm 1\rangle$.  And to figure out the reps. of $SU(2)$, one uses the fact that is complexified Lie algebra is equal to $\mathfrak{sl}_2$.  I think this is all explained in Fulton and Harris, ...

Comment: ... and in many other places too.  Regards,

Comment: @MattE: Thanks for your explanation. I think I will need to learn more to fully understand it.

Comment: @MattE: Can this be shown by some physical arguments?

Comment: @ramanujan_dirac: Dear ramanujan_dirac, I don't know off the top of my head, and I'm not sure I'm the right person to really answer this kind of question.  Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof is rather simple, just calculate characters (for rotations around OZ, since the axis does not affect the character) , and, using orthogonality theorem, note that all Fourier series coefficient for any other character are zero. But functions $\cos (l*\phi) (l - n)$, (where $n$ is an integer) form a complete set on $<0, \pi>$, so there are no more irreducible, unequivocal representations of $SO(3)$.

Comment: It makes sense. Why doesn't this work for $SO(4)$?

Comment: Characters of these representations for SO(3) are dependent only on one rotation parameter. This is not true for SO(4). You can find a basis of Lie algebra A1..A3, B1..B3 such that: [Ai, Aj] = const*Ak, [Bi, Bj] = const*Bk, [Ai,Bj] = 0 for any i, j. So SO(4) is isomorphic to SO(3) x SO(3). That means each conjugancy class is defined by two parameters, which makes further calculations much harder. Moreover, this method with Fourier series works for SO(3), only because the characters are some simple trigonometric functions, dependent on dimmension. In the general case it may not work.